# Display system in systeme

Tags: systeme

I'm new to the `systeme` package. I was reading the [manual](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/generic/systeme/systeme_fr.pdf) to get to know it, but unfortunately it is written in French. I want to typeset the following

[image]

The best I can come up with is the following code

```
\syscodeextracol{\kern 2.5em }{}
 \sysextracolsign{|}\sysdelim{\{}{|}\systeme{3x+7y=1 | 5,
        5x-8y=-18  |(-3)}
```

which is clearly not exactly what I want. Full MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\syscodeextracol{\kern 2.5em }{}
 \sysextracolsign{|}\sysdelim{\{}{|}\systeme{3x+7y=1 | 5,
        5x-8y=-18  |(-3)}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about consecutive `\systeme` directives?

[image]

The required amount of kerning between the `\systeme` blocks will depend on both the font size and the math and text fonts that are in use. For Computer Modern and a 12pt document font size, `\kern-26pt` looks "about right". If one were to load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` font packages, then `\kern-22pt` would be "about right".

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

 \sysdelim{\{}{|}
 \systeme{ 3x+7y=1 , 5x-8y=-18 }
 \kern-26pt % kerning amount obtained by trial and error :-)
 \sysdelim{.}{.} \sysalign{l,l}
 \systeme{ \cdot 5 , \cdot(-3) }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just set this as an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left\{\begin{array}{ @{} r @{} l | l @{} }
    3x + 7y ={} &   1 & \cdot 5    \\[\jot]
    5x - 8y ={} & -18 & \cdot (-3)
  \end{array}\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good old arrays. (+1)

Answer (score 7):

Not fully automated, but not difficult to input either: you use `\tr` in the top row, `\mr` in the middle rows and `\br` in the bottom row.

Each of these commands take an optional argument for extra depth (in `\tr`), extra height (in `\br`) and extra height and depth (in `\mr`) in case unusually high rows are present.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{systeme}

\newcommand{\tr}[1][0pt]{%
  \smash{%
    \vrule height \ht\strutbox depth \dimexpr\dp\strutbox+0.5ex+#1\relax
  }%
}
\newcommand{\mr}[1][0pt]{%
  \smash{
    \vrule height \dimexpr\ht\strutbox+0.5ex+#1\relax depth\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+0.5ex+#1\relax
  }%
}
\newcommand{\br}[1][0pt]{%
  \smash{
    \vrule height \dimexpr\ht\strutbox+0.5ex+#1\relax depth\dp\strutbox
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\syscodeextracol{\kern 0.5em $}{$}
\sysextracolsign{|}
\systeme{
  3x+7y=1   |\tr \cdot 5,
  5x-8y=-18 |\br \cdot (-3)
}
\]

\[
\syscodeextracol{\kern 0.5em $}{$}
\sysextracolsign{|}
\systeme{
  3x+7y+z=1   |\tr \cdot 5,
  5x-8y-z=-18 |\mr \cdot (-3),
  2x+y+z=2    |\br
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach, where you can independently add extra height and depth and also set the default vertical separation.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{systeme}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { tolaso/sysrules }
 {
  t .bool_set:N = \l__tolaso_sysrules_top_bool,
  b .bool_set:N = \l__tolaso_sysrules_bot_bool,
  m .code:n = \keys_set:nn { tolaso/sysrules } { t,b },
  h .dim_set:N = \l__tolaso_sysrules_extra_height_dim,
  d .dim_set:N = \l__tolaso_sysrules_extra_depth_dim,
  s .dim_set:N = \l__tolaso_sysrules_default_sep_dim,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\SEP}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { tolaso/sysrules } { s=0.5ex, #1 }
  \__tolaso_sysrules_make:
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__tolaso_sysrules_make:
 {
  \smash
   {
    \vrule
      height \dim_eval:n {
       \ht\strutbox + \l__tolaso_sysrules_extra_height_dim
       \bool_if:NF \l__tolaso_sysrules_top_bool { + \l__tolaso_sysrules_default_sep_dim }
      }
      depth \dim_eval:n { 
       \dp\strutbox + \l__tolaso_sysrules_extra_depth_dim
       \bool_if:NF \l__tolaso_sysrules_bot_bool { + \l__tolaso_sysrules_default_sep_dim }
      }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\syscodeextracol{\kern 0.5em $}{$}
\sysextracolsign{|}
\systeme{
  3x+7y=1   |\SEP{t} \cdot 5,
  5x-8y=-18 |\SEP{b} \cdot (-3)
}
\]

\[
\syscodeextracol{\kern 0.5em $}{$}
\sysextracolsign{|}
\systeme{
  3x+7y+z=1   |\SEP{t} \cdot 5,
  5x-8y-z=-18 |\SEP{} \cdot (-3),
  2x+y+z=2    |\SEP{b}
}
\]
\[
\syscodeextracol{\kern 0.5em $}{$}
\sysextracolsign{|}
\systeme{
  3x+7y+z=1   |\SEP{t} \cdot 5,
  5x-8y-z=-{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k} |\SEP{h=0.8ex,d=0.8ex} \cdot (-3),
  2x+y+z=2    |\SEP{b}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

For uniformity, you can say `\SEP{m}` for a middle row instead of `\SEP{}`.

[image]

Comment: Do you use LaTeX3 syntax? Anyway, your solution covers a more general case. (+1) though.